# Hybrid graphic cards performance on Xenial 16.04

Tags: 16.04, laptop, radeon, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have an issue with my grapihic card performance. I have laptop Lenovo g500H with integrated Intel GPU and additional AMD Radeon 8750m graphic card.
On 14.04 Trusty it worked fine. I just run `DRI_PRIME=1` and FPS amount was much better in `glxgears`. On 16.04 there is no performance improvement although i can see the Radeon card is running in `glxinfo`. I'm looking for the answer in a several tutorials and Q&A's but without any progress yet. 
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try out with several PPA:

[Updated and Optimized Open Graphics Drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)  (16.04, 17.10, 18.04)

[padoka PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa/) (18.04 only)

[Padoka Stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa)  (16.04, 17.10)

I use the second one for Radeon 6550HD running on 18.04 LTS. When i was on 16.04 i used Oibaf's PPA. Anyway, it's easy to revert.